# Data Scraping from PDF and Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, screen-scraping

I am doing a little data scraping, There are 3 types of file from which i am scraping data.
 1- HTML
 2- PDF
 3- Excel(xls)

For HTML i am comfortable, i am using HTML Agility for that.

For PDF and excel i need suggestions from anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning Excel. If you are in a MS environment you can either do Office Automation or use OLEDB. In a Java environment look at Apache POI.

EDIT: Concerning PDF in Java try [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) . Can also work in .NET using IKVM

Comment: Absolutely recommend POI if prefer a Java/Groovy solution.
Perl also has some pretty good APIs for spreadsheets and PDFs

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Cogniview's PDF2XL](http://www.cogniview.com/pdf2xl.php), a reasonably inexpensive commercial product, to extract data from tables in PDF files into Excel. We have used it with great success.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Agility is a library. Its good to use. But then, why do you need separate tools for different data extraction purposes? Use Automation Anywhere to extract data from any source. As far as I know, it would work for all the three sources you have specified.
Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UiPath](http://uipath.com) in order to achieve this. It can scrape 100% accurate PDF, Excel, HTML, Java, Windows, .NET, WPF, legacy. Also works with virtualized based environments but only via OCR scraping.

Can be used from code (SDK) but also you can create visual automation (workflows) using UiPath Studio.
Here's a tutorial on [web data extraction](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/web-data-extraction-automation)

**Note:** I work at UiPath so I know it can do the job. You should also try other visual automation tools like Automation Anywhere, WinAutomation, Jacada, use them side by side and choose the one that suits you the best.